# calculate zBuffer-accept wrong values

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, zbuffer

calculate zBuffer-accept wrong values

I am trying to calculate my zBuffer and I accept wrong values. the model that I am loading has to have diffrent Zbuffer values but I dont accept them my values are defined ZNEAR 1.0f ZFAR 1500.0f my code is:

```
//calculate the zBuffer
GLfloat get_gl_depth()
{
    Pipeline p;
    int w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    int h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo );
    glBufferData( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, w * h * sizeof( GLfloat ), 0, GL_STREAM_READ );
    glReadPixels( 0, 0, w, h, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0 );
    GLfloat* ptr = (GLfloat*)glMapBuffer( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY );

    unsigned short* buffer=new unsigned short[w*h];
    unsigned short* current = buffer;
    if (ptr != nullptr)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<w*h;i++)
        {
            GLfloat distance =ZNEAR+(GLfloat(ptr[i])*(ZFAR-ZNEAR));
            *current++ = unsigned short(distance + 0.5);
        }
    }

    glUnmapBuffer( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER );
    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0 );

    delete[] buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

After that I am calling a func that loads all this:

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

    const float lightZ =  (sinf(m_scale) + 1.0f) / 2.0f;
    PointLight pl[10];
    int numLights = 0;

    pl[numLights++] = CreateLight(0, 0, 0, 255.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    pl[numLights++] = CreateLight(0, 0, 100, 0.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f);
    pl[numLights++] = CreateLight(100, 0, 100, 0.0f, 0.0f, 255.0f);

    m_pEffect->SetPointLights(numLights, pl);


    m_pEffect->SetPointLights(3, pl);

    Pipeline p;

    Vector3f cameraUp = CameraUpVector();
    p.SetCamera(m_cameraPosition, m_cameraTarget, cameraUp);

    p.SetPerspectiveProj(60.0f, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, ZNEAR, ZFAR);
    m_pEffect->SetWVP(p.GetWVPTrans());
    m_pEffect->SetWorldMatrix(p.GetWorldTrans());
    m_pEffect->SetDirectionalLight(m_directionalLight);
    m_pEffect->SetEyeWorldPos(m_cameraPosition);
    m_pEffect->SetMatSpecularIntensity(0.0f);
    m_pEffect->SetMatSpecularPower(0);

    m_pMesh->Render();
    get_gl_depth(/*WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT*/);
    glutSwapBuffers();

This is the func that initlize the first values:
```

Vector3f Pos(0.0f, 0.0f, -700.0f);

```
    Vector3f Target(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.00001f);
    Vector3f Up(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    m_cameraPosition = Pos;

    m_cameraTarget = Target;
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but depth values in the depth buffer are non-linear when using perspective projection, so depending on what you expect from  your distance calculation you may be disappointed :)

Comment: can you show us a sample of the values you are getting ? It's also good to point out that when your vertex is converted to NDC it is no more using right hand coordinate system, but the z is actually flipped

Comment: I accept only 1.0000000 float in the values of the array ptr without any change, when I expect to accept different values because I have some building in my model that includes different hight

Comment: what do u mean "converted to NDC"?Thanks

Comment: @user3436304 NDC (Normalized Device Coordinates), after projection it is scaled into [-1,1] and the z is flipped.

Comment: maybe I have to change the zFar and zNear?

Comment: @user3436304 no SetPerspectiveProj is fine. What I mean is that you need to take what I said in the first comment into consideration. But again you didn't show us example values you read from the depth buffer and the result distance.

Comment: I see that the distance stays on value 1500 float as the value of the zFar.
The values of the current (which I copy the zBuffer into it) are 52685 in all current,100000(array place)